# Sleep statement in Ruby doesn't accept any rails convertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found this very weird. Why am I not able to do this?:

```
puts Time.now
x=2
puts x
puts x.class
sleep x
puts Time.now
x=x.seconds
puts x
puts x.class
sleep (x)
puts Time.now
```

The output I get is:

```
Mon Oct 01 16:14:58 +0530 2012
2
Fixnum
Mon Oct 01 16:15:00 +0530 2012
2
Fixnum
rake aborted!
can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into time interval
/Users/hariharanganapathiraman/Documents/MigrationScripts/sample/lib/import/boot.rb:23:in `sleep'
```

Similarly it doesn't work for `.minutes` or `.days`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `ActiveSupport::Duration` mimics itself as `Fixnum` class:

```
ActiveSupport::Duration.new(3600, [[:seconds, 3600]]).class #=> Fixnum
```

Use `sleep(2.seconds.to_i)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `ActiveSupport::Duration`
It's inherited from `BasicObject` that have only limited number of methods and does not have `class` method.
If you take a look in ActiveSupport::Duration [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L104) you'll see that all methods are proxied(via method_missing) to `@value`, that's Fixnum in your case.

Hence, since `ActiveSupport::Duration` has no class method, your class call for a `x.seconds`
 goes to `Fixnum`.